# Digital Numbers on Tesseract OCR

Tags: android, opencv, tesseract

**SOLUTION:**

I've had to train my own data to try it with the OCR. It seems that works well, but I don't know why the trained data from arturaugusto not works for me =(

https://github.com/adri1992/Tesseract_sevenSegmentsLetsGoDigital.git

With my trained data, to get good results of the OCR, I've done this phases (I've done it with OpenCV):

- First, convert the image to Black&White
- Second, apply to the image a Gaussian Blur
- Third, apply to the image a Threshold filter

With this, the seven segments digits are recognized.

**QUESTION:**

I'm trying to get an OCR through Tesseract on Android, and I'm testing the app with this image (via [Text detection on Seven Segment Display via Tesseract OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672705/text-detection-on-seven-segment-display-via-tesseract-ocr)):

[image: OCR test image]

I'm using the data trained by arturaugusto (https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr), but the wrong result of the OCR is:

884288

The zero is recognized  as an eight, and I don't know why.

I'm applying to the image a Gaussian Blur and a threshold filter, via OpenCV, and the image processed is this:

[image: OCR Image processed]

Is there any other data trained or do you know any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey adri, any updates in your solution? :-)

Comment: Hi Felipe! I've trained my own data... Try it https://github.com/adri1992/Tesseract_sevenSegmentsLetsGoDigital and check me if it works for you. Remember to do all phases that I comment in the "solution" section of the post

Comment: I managed to process your test image using python pillow and reaching a bw image similar to yours, but when I run tesseract with your trained data it returns an empty page (!). I'm not sure if I installed the trained data correctly... I copied everything to the folder /opt/local/share/tessdata (I'm on Mac OS X). When I run tesseract --list-langs the "lets" language is shown. Do you have any tips? By the way, your training data stopped mistaking "0" for "8" (as you stated in your question)?

Comment: Thanks adri1992 for your trained data.

Comment: hello, @adri1992 were you able to do it? I am stuck at the final stage from last 2 days

Comment: Hi Zeeshan! I trained my own data. It should be working with that concrete font https://github.com/adri1992/Tesseract_sevenSegmentsLetsGoDigital

Comment: @adri1992 I using your trained data and blurred image in tesseractapi, the result perfect.when i tried to blur by followed your steps,not perfect. there might be different perimeters. could you share the piece of code of three steps. More helpful .Thank You.

Comment: @Felipe Ferri : I have the same issu, but I am on Windows. Did you get able to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using erode to fill the gaps between the segments.
I think the problem is that tesseract can't handle well segmented font.

With OpenCV-python, I use `cv2.erode(display,kernel, iterations = erosion_iters)` to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to fill the gaps between the segments, but it not works for me either :(
I have trained my own data with the same font, and now, I don't know exactly why, the OCR works well with this new trained data.
In some minutes I'll update the question with the solution and the repository direction.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you clarify what you are declaring `display` and `kernel` as earlier in the code? (eg is it an import of some kind?)

Comment: @takanuva15, for take this example:

import cv2;
import numpy as np;
display = cv2.imread('display.png',0);
kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8);
eroded_img = cv2.erode(display, kernel, iterations = 1);