# Using SSOCR for 7-Segment Display in Android

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to recognize the digital numbers in Android. I used OpenCV for image processing and OCR engine for Tessreact. But result is still poor.

I found about SSOCR form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361213/7-segment-display-ocr?rq=1). Therefore I would like to use [SSOCR](https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~auerswal/ssocr/) (Seven Segment Optical Character Recognition) in Android. It is written in C. Anyone suggests me the way how can I use SSOCR in my Android application OR is there any better way to recognize the digital numbers with tessreact.

Comment: did you find any solution?